# Tools for Importing/working with SEED seismographic data in Mathematica?

Tags: import, data

Do you know if exist a library or a package in order to import and work with SEED Seismographic data in Mathematica?

Comment: You will have to write your own importers. I wrote my own SAC reader, which I can post, but `rdseed` is your best option for working with SEED files (use it to convert to SAC).

Comment: Thanks! Can you share your SAC reader?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best tool to work with the [SEED format](http://www.iris.edu/ds/nodes/dmc/data/formats/) would be IRIS' own [`rdseed`](http://www.iris.edu/ds/nodes/dmc/software/downloads/rdseed/) program. It might be possible to use [`Jrdseed`](http://www.iris.edu/ds/nodes/dmc/forms/jrdseed/) with JLink and *Mathematica*, but I have not tried this. Typically SEED files are converted to other convenient formats for data processing, of which the [SAC (Seismic Analysis Code)](http://www.iris.edu/ds/nodes/dmc/software/downloads/sac/) format is the most common one.

#### Implementation:

The following is my implementation of a [SAC format](http://www.iris.edu/files/sac-manual/manual/file_format.html) reader which I used regularly in my work:

```
(* Helper functions *)
packed = Developer`ToPackedArray;
fromJulianDay = DatePlus[{#, 1, 1}, #2 - 1] &;
monthOfJulianDay = fromJulianDay[#, #2][[2]]&;

(* ReadSAC *)
ReadSAC[file_String, flag: All | "RawHeader" | "Header" | "ShowHeader" | "Data"] :=
        Module[{str = OpenRead[file, BinaryFormat -> True], h1, h2, h3, header, niceHeader, data, fixTrim, tidyUp},
            fixTrim = (ToCharacterCode[#] /. {Longest[x__?Positive], ___} :> FromCharacterCode[{x}])&;
            tidyUp = # /. {
                (HoldPattern["UNUSED" -> _] | HoldPattern["INTERNAL" -> _]) :> Sequence[],
                Rule[_, -12345 | -12345. | "-12345"] -> Sequence[], (* Undefined *)
                Rule[l_?(StringMatchQ[#, "L"~~__]&), r_] :> l -> (r /. {1 -> True, 0 -> False}),
                Rule[l_, r_String] :> l -> fixTrim@r (* strip trailing chars after null char *)
            }&;

            h1 = Thread[
                {
                    "DELTA"  , "DEPMIN"   , "DEPMAX" , "SCALE"    , "ODELTA"   , "B"        , "E"        , "O"        ,
                    "A"      , "INTERNAL" , "T0"     , "T1"       , "T2"       , "T3"       , "T4"       , "T5"       ,
                    "T6"     , "T7"       , "T8"     , "T9"       , "F"        , "RESP0"    , "RESP1"    , "RESP2"    ,
                    "RESP3"  , "RESP4"    , "RESP5"  , "RESP6"    , "RESP7"    , "RESP8"    , "RESP9"    , "STLA"     ,
                    "STLO"   , "STEL"     , "STDP"   , "EVLA"     , "EVLO"     , "EVEL"     , "EVDP"     , "MAG"      ,
                    "USER0"  , "USER1"    , "USER2"  , "USER3"    , "USER4"    , "USER5"    , "USER6"    , "USER7"    ,
                    "USER8"  , "USER9"    , "DIST"   , "AZ"       , "BAZ"      , "GCARC"    , "INTERNAL" , "INTERNAL" ,
                    "DEPMEN" , "CMPAZ"    , "CMPINC" , "XMINIMUM" , "XMAXIMUM" , "YMINIMUM" , "YMAXIMUM" , "UNUSED"   ,
                    "UNUSED" , "UNUSED"   , "UNUSED" , "UNUSED"   , "UNUSED"   , "UNUSED"
                } -> BinaryReadList[str, "Real32", 70]
            ];

            h2 = Thread[
                {
                    "NZYEAR" , "NZJDAY"   , "NZHOUR" , "NZMIN"  , "NZSEC"  , "NZMSEC" , "NVHDR"  , "NORID"   , "NEVID"   ,
                    "NPTS"   , "INTERNAL" , "NWFID"  , "NXSIZE" , "NYSIZE" , "UNUSED" , "IFTYPE" , "IDEP"    , "IZTYPE"  ,
                    "UNUSED" , "IINST"    , "ISTREG" , "IEVREG" , "IEVTYP" , "IQUAL"  , "ISYNTH" , "IMAGTYP" , "IMAGSRC" ,
                    "UNUSED" , "UNUSED"   , "UNUSED" , "UNUSED" , "UNUSED" , "UNUSED" , "UNUSED" , "UNUSED"  , "LEVEN"   ,
                    "LPSPOL" , "LOVROK"   , "LCALDA" , "UNUSED"
                } -> BinaryReadList[str, "Integer32", 40]
            ];

            h3 = Thread[
                {
                    "KSTNM"  , "KEVNM"  , "KHOLE" , "KO"  , "KA"  , "KT0" , "KT1"    , "KT2"    , "KT3"    , "KT4"    ,
                    "KT5"    , "KT6"    , "KT7"   , "KT8" , "KT9" , "KF"  , "KUSER0" , "KUSER1" , "KUSER2" , "KCMPNM" ,
                    "KNETWK" , "KDATRD" , "KINST"
                } -> Map[
                    Composition[StringTrim, StringJoin],
                    Internal`PartitionRagged[BinaryReadList[str, "Character8", 192], {8, 16} ~ Join ~ ConstantArray[8, 21]]
                ]
            ];

            header = tidyUp@Join[h1, h2, h3];
            niceHeader = {
                        "Type" -> "SAC", "StationCode" -> "KSTNM", "Network" -> "KNETWK", "Component" -> "KCMPNM",
                        "Location" -> {"STLA", "STLO"}, "SamplingFrequency" -> 1 / "DELTA", "Samples" -> "NPTS",
                        "Date" -> Hold[fromJulianDay["NZYEAR", "NZJDAY"] ~ Join ~ {"NZHOUR", "NZMIN", "NZSEC"}],
                        "Year" -> "NZYEAR", "Month" -> Hold[monthOfJulianDay["NZYEAR", "NZJDAY"]]
                    } /. header // ReleaseHold // Association;
            If[!StringMatchQ[ToString@flag, "*Header"], data = packed@N@BinaryReadList[str, "Real32"]];

            Close@str;

            Switch[flag,
                "Data", data,
                "Header", niceHeader,
                "RawHeader", header,
                "ShowHeader", header /. Rule -> List // TableForm // Panel,
                All, <|niceHeader, "FileName" -> file, "Data" -> data|>
            ]
        ]

ReadSAC[file_String] := ReadSAC[file, All]
```

#### Usage:

You can read the header info for a SAC file as `ReadSAC["filename", "Header"]` (I'm not including a SAC file for this example):

[image]

This is obviously a "cleaned" up version of the header and if you'd like to view the raw header (as described in the SAC format), you can use `"RawHeader"` as the second argument.

The entire file can be read with `ReadSAC["filename"]` or `ReadSAC["filename", All]` and the output is again an association. In addition to the keys found in the header above, the association also has `"FileName"` and `"Data"` as keys when reading the entire file.

You can also just ask for the seismic data directly with `"Data"` as the second argument, and in this case, the output is a list of data points (that have not been corrected for instrument response).